# Delete placemark from within balloon popup

Tags: javascript, dom-events, google-earth-plugin

I'm experimenting with the Google Earth Plugin API for an application that I'm writing. I want to be able to delete placemarks from the map. The simplest way I could think of to do this is to create a balloon popup with a 'Delete' link but I've been unable to figure out how to do delete:

```
balloon.setContentString(
'Location: ' + event.getLatitude().toString() + ", " +
event.getLongitude().toString() + '<br />&nbsp;<br />' +
'<a href="#" onclick="ge.getFeatures().removeChild(event.getCurrentTarget())">Delete</a><br /><a href="#" onclick="prompt(\'Enter new name\', \'blah\'\)">Rename</a>');
```

This results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<MouseEvent> has no method 'getCurrentTarget' earth2.html:1 onclick
```

(As you can see I also want to be able to rename, but presumably that won't be so hard to figure out when I've figured out deleting?)

The entire code can be found at:

http://chrishowells.co.uk:81/earth2.html

The entire block:

```
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getWindow(), 'mousedown', function(event) {
if (event.getTarget().getType() == 'KmlPlacemark' &&
    event.getTarget().getGeometry().getType() == 'KmlPoint') {
  // don't show the default popup
  //http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#javascript_in_balloons
  event.preventDefault();

var balloon = ge.createHtmlStringBalloon('');
balloon.setFeature(event.getTarget());
//balloon.setMaxWidth(300);

balloon.setContentString(
  'Location: ' + event.getLatitude().toString() + ", " +
event.getLongitude().toString() + '<br />&nbsp;<br />' +
'<a href="#" onclick="ge.getFeatures().removeChild(event.getCurrentTarget())">Delete</a><br /><a href="#" onclick="prompt(\'Enter new name\', \'blah\'\)">Rename</a>');
ge.setBalloon(balloon);

var placemark = event.getTarget();

dragInfo = {
    placemark: event.getTarget(),
    dragged: false
  };
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is telling you exactly what the problem is.

```
 Object #<MouseEvent> has no method 'getCurrentTarget'
```

The issue being that within the `onclick` event handler of the anchor the `event` variable referrers to the click on the link rather than the click on the placemark. That is the `event` is a DOM mouse event rather than a KmlMouseEvent.

Also, the method you need to call to reference the object to which the KMLEvent was originally dispatched  is `getTarget`.

See the API guide for KmlEvent.getTarget:
https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_event#adfee4d0797ff7d437e77c649673f9ffc

To fix this you need to do a number of things, firstly define a global variable to hold any current placemark click event. Do this at the top of the script where you define the `ge` variable add a `currentEvent` variable as well. i.e.

```
var ge = null; 
var currentEvent = null;
```

Secondly your `mousedown` listener should be ammended to allow the javascript in the balloon to reference the `currentEvent` variable you have defined.

Finally, you should then use the `currentEvent` variable to reference the Placemark to remove it via the code in the balloon.

For example.

```
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getWindow(), 'mousedown', function(event) {

    if (event.getTarget().getType() == 'KmlPlacemark' &&
    event.getTarget().getGeometry().getType() == 'KmlPoint') {
        currentEvent = event; // used in the balloon content string
        event.preventDefault();

        var balloon = ge.createHtmlStringBalloon('');
        balloon.setFeature(event.getTarget());

        balloon.setContentString(
        'Location: ' + event.getLatitude().toString() + ", " +
        event.getLongitude().toString() + '<br />&nbsp;<br />' +
        '<a href="#" onclick="ge.getFeatures().removeChild(currentEvent.getTarget());ge.setBalloon(null);">Delete</a><br /><a href="#" onclick="prompt(\'Enter new name\', \'blah\'\)">Rename</a>');
        ge.setBalloon(balloon);

        dragInfo = {
            placemark: event.getTarget(),
            dragged: false
        };
    }
});
```

I have tested this fully and it works AOK, when you click `delete` the placemark is removed and the current balloon is closed.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Fraser. I had also tried that, unfortunately it doesn't work either: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<MouseEvent> has no method 'getTarget'`. Which suggests to me that in the onclick the event is referring to the wrong thing. I don't ask questions without spending a long time researching via Google, reading the documentation, or just experimenting (and I've spent several hours doing all three) but unfortunately I've not been able to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, yes `event` refers to the DOM event on the anchor rather than the KML mouse event on the placemark. Please see my edited answer...The `getTarget` vs `getCurrentTarget` still applies as I first stated though...

Comment: Superb, many thanks. That worked perfectly. Looks like I need to dig deeper into the basics (DOM etc) before diving headfirst into JavaScript... must be 15 years since I learnt HTML... many thanks. Acquired a copy of JavaScript The Definitive Guide today so will plough on. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, it is actually a bit of a tricky one to spot as the variable `event` within the onlick="(here)" handler is an http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp whilst the `event` parameter for your Google Earth listener is an https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_event#adfee4d0797ff7d437e77c649673f9ffc - so whilst the code looks totally correct the two `event` variables are actually referring to two totally different objects. Anyhow, glad to have helped....